# How to prevent second script to run after first succeeded in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I did a script in bash, but it geets in some sort of a loop. My script is like a reverse operation with an systemctl service and it's running like this :

```
if systemctl status service | grep -q "Active: inactive"; then
    read -r -p "Service is inactive do you want to start it? : [y/N] : " response
    if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
    then
        systemctl start `service` && echo "Service is active"
    else
        echo "Service stays inactive"
    fi
fi


if systemctl status service | grep -q 'Active: active'; then
    read -r -p "Service is active, do you want to stop it? [y/N] : " response
    if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
    then
        systemctl stop service && echo "Service is inactive"
    else
        echo "Service stays active"
    fi
fi
```

The problem is when it reach the first part and I want to start it, it jumps to the second part when it asks me if I want to stop it, is there any way to prevent bash doing this and stop it?

Comment: Don't grep the output of `systemctl status`. Instead, use `if systemctl is-active service; then ...`

Comment: What's with the backticks around the service name on the fifth line? And if you want to skip the second `if` block if the first one triggered, then don't make it a separate `if` block at all; make it an `else` clause.

Comment: Sounds like you want `else`

Comment: the backtick is by accident, I'l try with an else

Comment: (oh -- `systemctl -q is-active service`, if you want no incidental output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `else` block:

```
toggle_service() {
  local response service=$1
  if systemctl is-active "$service"; then
    read -r -p "Service is inactive do you want to start it? : [y/N] : " response
    if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
        systemctl start "$service" && echo "Service is active" >&2
    else
        echo "Service stays inactive"
    fi
  else
    read -r -p "Service is active, do you want to stop it? [y/N] : " response
    if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
      systemctl stop "$service" && echo "Service is inactive" >&2
    else
      echo "Service stays active" >&2
    fi
  fi
}
```

...or, a [DRYer version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
toggle_service() {
  local action state_name response service=$1
  if systemctl is-active "$service"; then
    state_name=active; action=stop
  else
    state_name=inactive; action=start
  fi
  read -r -p "Service is ${state_name}, do you want to ${action} it?" response
  if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
    systemctl "$action" "$service" && echo "Action complete: ${action} ${service}" >&2
  else
    echo "${service} remains ${state_name}" >&2
  fi
}
```

Either one can be invoked with:

```
toggle_service sshd
```

Comment: What's `local action state_name response service=$1`  doing

Comment: Stopping variables from leaking outside your function. Normally when you say `service=$1` in a function, it sets a variable named `service` in your shell's global scope. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/local

Comment: Fairs, thank you very much. I'm still learning this and I know these are rookie mistakes but I'm trying to get used to it.